# Web Management Service fails to start automatically

Tags: iis, service, startup, trace

After a reboot `Web Management Service` fails to start. I see the following error in Event Log

```
Unable to bind to the underlying transport for 192.168.0.101:8172. The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference to an interface which may not exist on this machine.  The data field contains the error number.
```

I replaced my real IP with `192.168.0.101`.

The problem seems to be obvious - someone else is using port 8172 during `Web Management Service` startup... but how do I find which process was it?

If I run service manually it starts successfully, meaning whatever is blocking 8172 is down by the time I can log into the box. Is there any way to trace usage of the ports by application during startup?

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5.

Comment: How does the message `The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference to an interface which may not exist on this machine.` leads you to the conclusion that `someone else is using port 8172 during ... startup`?

Comment: Mostly google (there are a lot of issues with port 80 being used by something else and the message is the same) and the fact that I can start the service manually after a few seconds. But I might be completely wrong...

Comment: I changed startup type from Automatic to Delayed using `sc config WMSVC start=delayed-auto` command. It works as workaround, but I still have no idea why the service fails to start during boot time

Comment: Got the exact same issue here - did you find anything further?